# How to make MSVC generate assembly which caches memory in a register?

Tags: c++, assembly, visual-c++, matrix-multiplication, simd

I have a type `mat4` which represents a `float[4][4]`. Internally it uses a 512-bit register.

```
union alignas(16 * sizeof(float)) mat4 {
private:
    __m512 m512;
    __m512d m512d;
    ALWAYS_INLINE mat4(__m512 m512) : m512{m512} {}
    ALWAYS_INLINE mat4(__m512d m512d) : m512d{m512d} {}
    ALWAYS_INLINE operator __m512&() { return m512; }
    ALWAYS_INLINE operator __m512d&() { return m512d; }
    ALWAYS_INLINE operator const __m512&() const { return m512; }
    ALWAYS_INLINE operator const __m512d&() const { return m512d; }
    ALWAYS_INLINE mat4& operator=(__m512 _m512) {
        m512 = _m512;
        return *this;
    }
    ALWAYS_INLINE mat4& operator=(__m512d _m512d) {
        m512d = _m512d;
        return *this;
    }

public:
    friend void __vectorcall transform_children(mat4 parent, std::span<mat4> children);
};
```

I also have a function `transform_children(mat4 parent, std::span<mat4> children)`. It treats all `mat4`s as transformation matrices and transforms all the `children` (in place) by multiplying them with the `parent`. I wrote<sup>1</sup> an optimised implementation using AVX512F intrinsics.

```
void __vectorcall transform_children(mat4 parent, std::span<mat4> children) {
    mat4* const __restrict bs = children.data();
    const size_t n = children.size();

    ASSUME(n != 0);

    const mat4 zmm1 = _mm512_permute_ps(parent, 0);
    const mat4 zmm2 = _mm512_permute_ps(parent, 85);
    const mat4 zmm3 = _mm512_permute_ps(parent, 170);
    const mat4 zmm0 = _mm512_permute_ps(parent, 255);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        mat4& __restrict zmm4 = bs[i];
        mat4 zmm5 = _mm512_shuffle_f64x2(zmm4, zmm4, 85);
        zmm5 = _mm512_mul_ps(zmm5, zmm2);
        mat4 zmm6 = _mm512_shuffle_f64x2(zmm4, zmm4, 0);
        zmm6 = _mm512_fmadd_ps(zmm1, zmm6, zmm5);
        zmm5 = _mm512_shuffle_f64x2(zmm4, zmm4, 170);
        zmm4 = _mm512_shuffle_f64x2(zmm4, zmm4, 255);
        zmm4 = _mm512_fmadd_ps(zmm0, zmm4, zmm6);
        zmm4 = _mm512_fmadd_ps(zmm3, zmm5, zmm4);
    }
}
```

Both [GCC](https://godbolt.org/z/chf6dcnGn) and [Clang](https://godbolt.org/z/zxTv5bxfK) compile this nearly literally to optimised assembly. Unfortunately, [MSVC](https://godbolt.org/z/z88hT36WT) does something weird. For some reason, instead of loading the value of `bs[i]` to a register and then storing it back to the array at the end of the iteration, it accesses the memory 4 times:

```
void transform_children(mat4,std::span<mat4,4294967295>) PROC ; transform_children, COMDAT
        mov     ecx, DWORD PTR _children$[esp]
        vpermilps zmm4, zmm0, 0
        vpermilps zmm5, zmm0, 85                        
        vpermilps zmm6, zmm0, 170                 
        vpermilps zmm7, zmm0, 255                 
        test    ecx, ecx
        je      SHORT $LN36@transform_
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR _children$[esp-4]
        npad    8
$LL4@transform_:
        lea     eax, DWORD PTR [eax+64]
        vmovupd zmm3, ZMMWORD PTR [eax-64]              ; HERE
        vshuff64x2 zmm0, zmm3, zmm3, 85       
        vmulps  zmm0, zmm0, zmm5
        vshuff64x2 zmm1, zmm3, zmm3, 0
        vmovups zmm2, zmm4
        vfmadd213ps zmm2, zmm1, zmm0 
        vshuff64x2 zmm0, zmm3, zmm3, 255 
        vmovupd ZMMWORD PTR [eax-64], zmm0              ; HERE
        vfmadd231ps zmm2, zmm7, ZMMWORD PTR [eax-64]    ; HERE
        vshuff64x2 zmm1, zmm3, zmm3, 170               
        vmovups zmm0, zmm6
        vfmadd213ps zmm0, zmm1, zmm2
        vmovups ZMMWORD PTR [eax-64], zmm0              ; HERE
        sub     ecx, 1
        jne     SHORT $LL4@transform_
$LN36@transform_:
        vzeroupper
        ret     8
void transform_children(mat4,std::span<mat4,4294967295>) ENDP ; transform_children
```

What could I do to make MSVC access memory only twice, like GCC and Clang<sup>2</sup> do?

---

<sup>1. To be precise, GCC and Clang wrote this implementation (sort of). First, I wrote a the typical implementation using two nested loops. Then, I ran it through GCC using `-mavx512f`. GCC was smart enough to generate optimised vectorised code. Then, I converted this vectorised code from assembly back to C++ using intrinsics. Then, I compiled the new intrinsic code with Clang and it generated an even faster vectorised assembly. Then I converted Clang's assembly to C++ intrinsics again.</sup>

<sup>2. Clang accesses memory 4 times, but it unrolls the loop, so still two accesses per iteration</sup>

Comment: FYI, normally you shouldn't just use `-mavx512f`.  Use `gcc -O3 -ffast-math -march=skylake-avx512` or `icelake-client` or `-march=native` to enable all the other AVX-512 extensions on your CPU, and non-avx512 stuff like bmi1/2.  Plus tuning options; you might want `-mpreferred-vector-width=512` if it's worth auto-vectorizing other code with 512-bit vectors, since you're already using them here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TL:DR: it turns out that MSVC does a bad job when it has to convert between `__m512d` and `__m512` through the overloaded conversions of your `mat4` class.  So just do everything with `__m512` intrinsics, including the shuffling of 128-bit lanes.

---

MSVC making worse code is unfortunate but not shocking; MSVC's optimizer is [well known](https://www.agner.org/optimize/blog/read.php?i=1015) to be not as good in general.  MSVC doesn't do strict-aliasing, although `__m512` can alias anything anyway so IDK if that's relevant here.

Seems like you should just use a `__m512` (or maybe `mat4`) temporary variable instead of telling the compiler to modify `bs[i]` repeatedly and hope it actually doesn't.

Especially across implicit conversion from `__m512d` (from the `pd` aka `f64` shuffles) to `mat4` to `__m512` (for single-precision FMAs) and back.  `_mm512_shuffle_f32x4` is a drop-in replacement for `_mm512_shuffle_f64x2`; both use the shuffle-control immediate to select 128-bit lanes, and 32 vs. 64-bit element granularity for masking doesn't matter since you're not masking.  **It's more idiomatic to be using `f32x4` shuffles on packed-float data, so generally prefer that anyway.**

Writing it like this gets MSVC to make the asm you want; using a `__m512` variable required me to make the intrinsics types all match (if I didn't want to sprinkle it with `_mm512_castps_pd` and `pd_ps` around the shuffles); in fact that's what first let to me noticing the `__m512d` vs. `__m512` type difference.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        __m512 zmm4 = bs[i];
        mat4 zmm5 = _mm512_shuffle_f32x4(zmm4, zmm4, 85);
        zmm5 = _mm512_mul_ps(zmm5, zmm2);
        mat4 zmm6 = _mm512_shuffle_f32x4(zmm4, zmm4, 0);
        zmm6 = _mm512_fmadd_ps(zmm1, zmm6, zmm5);
        zmm5 = _mm512_shuffle_f32x4(zmm4, zmm4, 170);
        zmm4 = _mm512_shuffle_f32x4(zmm4, zmm4, 255);
        zmm4 = _mm512_fmadd_ps(zmm0, zmm4, zmm6);
        zmm4 = _mm512_fmadd_ps(zmm3, zmm5, zmm4);
        bs[i] = zmm4;
    }
```

MSVC 19.32 ([Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/KrEqsn5jM), same as v19.latest) is reloading your `zmm0` constant from `_zmm0$1$[esp+64]` at the bottom of the loop, right before the `vmovups [eax-64], zmm1` store into `bs[i]`.  It seems to use ZMM3 as a temporary later in the loop, overwriting the constant.  It also has a couple instructions like `vmovups zmm1, zmm7`.

But that only happens in a 32-bit build like you linked, not a normal 64-bit build like https://godbolt.org/z/GWszEnfP5 where it doesn't spill any vector constants to the stack.  (It does save/restore XMM6 and 7, though; IDK if Windows x64 made XMM16..31 all call-preserved like XMM6..15 are.  You'd hope not, that's way too many call-preserved registers.)  It still only used ZMM0..7, so it could have done that in 32-bit code, it just failed.

GCC targeting 32-bit mode with `-mabi=ms` doesn't have those wasted zmm to zmm move instructions; it's able to arrange its FMAs to modify `zmm4` (in ZMM0) in-place, scheduling the shuffles appropriately so the registers can be reused.  (https://godbolt.org/z/9sGbYn71o)

#### Using the same vector type for all intrinsics also works for MSVC

Even with the reference, we get asm without extra store/reload of `zmm4` [on Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/vfPj1hfzn) with x86 MSVC v19.latest after **just changing the shuffles to be `f32x4`.**

```
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        mat4& __restrict zmm4 = bs[i];
        mat4 zmm5 = _mm512_shuffle_f32x4(zmm4, zmm4, 85);
        zmm5 = _mm512_mul_ps(zmm5, zmm2);
        mat4 zmm6 = _mm512_shuffle_f32x4(zmm4, zmm4, 0);
        zmm6 = _mm512_fmadd_ps(zmm1, zmm6, zmm5);
        zmm5 = _mm512_shuffle_f32x4(zmm4, zmm4, 170);
        zmm4 = _mm512_shuffle_f32x4(zmm4, zmm4, 255);
        zmm4 = _mm512_fmadd_ps(zmm0, zmm4, zmm6);
        zmm4 = _mm512_fmadd_ps(zmm3, zmm5, zmm4);
        //bs[i] = zmm4;
    }
```

I think it's more idiomatic to write code as loading a vector into a register, then processing, then storing back to memory.  Especially with a name like `zmm4`, that seems odd for a reference variable; if you're thinking in terms of asm and registers, reference variables aren't a thing.  A name like `zmm4` doesn't imply any magic that will leave memory updated after modifying a register.

Using a non-reference means you're only modifying a local `__m512` (or `mat4` if you want to use a non-reference `mat4`), which is always easier for compilers to optimize into a register.  (Although in your loop there aren't any other memory references that it could alias with, even without `__restrict`.)

---

BTW, intrinsics let you use slightly meaningful names for vector variables, like `vmat`, `mati`, `vbsi`, or `vchild`, not `zmm4`.  It's unlikely that the compiler will actually keep your C++ `zmm4` variable in the ZMM4 register, so it's more mental effort to compare the asm to the C++ when naming vars this way.  e.g. you get instructions like `vmovups zmm3, ZMMWORD PTR _zmm0$1$[esp+64]`

Using names like `zmm0` is usually throwing away one of the clarity / readability advantages of intrinsics over assembly.

In fact you'd prefer the compiler to use ZMM16..31 so it wouldn't need a `vzeroupper` when it's done.  Except you linked a 32-bit build on Godbolt??  That's weird, so you only have ZMM0..7.  You linked a 64-bit build for GCC.

Comment: Thanks. I am more of an assembly reader than writer. I mixed single precision and double precision intrinsics because that's what Clang did. I just saw that it generated code which was one instruction shorter than GCC and just went with it. Good to know that in this case they have equivalent performance. I named the variables `zmmN` to be able to compare my code with the original assembly to be sure that I didn't make any mistakes when translating it. I totally didn't notice that the MSVC build was 32 bit. It was supposed to be 64 bit, but it seems that ultimately it provided some insights.

Comment: @janekb04: Ok fair enough, translating assembly back to intrinsics does justify using variable names like `zmm0`.  Although you might still rename one important variable, like in this case `zmm4` once you're done.  And yeah, clang's shuffle optimizer has its own preferences that don't include trying to match the element type in surrounding instructions; in asm registers are just registers (and it's only FP vs. SIMD-integer that ever has extra bypass forwarding latency, e.g. an FP blend between integer instructions).

Answer (score 3):

By defining these

```
ALWAYS_INLINE operator __m512&() { return m512; }
ALWAYS_INLINE operator __m512d&() { return m512d; }
ALWAYS_INLINE operator const __m512&() const { return m512; }
ALWAYS_INLINE operator const __m512d&() const { return m512d; }
```

you technically break the grounding for `__restrict`: the references returned in different places in the intrinsics using `zmm4` point to the same locations, so you are aliasing. It seems that MSVC++ correctly concludes that you are aliasing. Thus the compiler reloads the value from memory each time.

Please, note that your `__restrict` here says about the `this` reference of a `mat4` object, but not about the references returned by the conversion operators quoted above:

```
mat4& __restrict zmm4 = bs[i];
```

Not only are you aliasing, but you are also punning the type (though in a legal way - through a `union`).

The best solution should be to use the casting intrinsics, as well as store the temporary values in a dedicated `const` variable. This way you should get the optimizations.

Comment: Oh yeah, I didn't look at the actual implementation of that union when writing my answer and wondering about that `__restrict` promise.  That's nasty; I'd assumed there's just be a single `float[8]` or `__m512` member, like how Agner Fog implements implicit conversions in VCL from `Vec4f` to `__m128` and so on.  (https://github.com/vectorclass/version2/blob/08959ebe6ea5d8317330b242e28ba0d2938ac52f/vectorf128.h#L92 is Vec4fb, a boolean vector like from FP compares; it's implicit conversion read operators only return by value, not reference, although assignment returns a reference.)

Comment: *Thus the compiler reloads the value from memory each time.* - It doesn't have to do that; correctness is possible without reloading since it is after all the same memory with no intervening stores that could change it.  But doing it this way certainly doesn't make it easy for the compiler.  (And if there's undefined behaviour, that's always bad.)

Comment: It seems that all the issues come from mixing the single precision and double precision intrinsics together. If I didn't do that, I wouldn't have needed to use a `union` on `__m512` and `__m512d` and these conversions.